# Avoid rounding errors in SSRS for small values

Tags: sql, regex, reporting-services, formatting, rounding-error

Using SQL Server Reporting Services, if a value in the database is zero, the following format expression with convert it to --- properly to 2 decimal places:

## ,0.00;(#,0.00);'---'

However, if the value is 0.001, and the report needs to display to 2 decimals (i.e. should show 0.00) the resulting format --- still shows up in the report.

Is there a way to avoid these rounding issues in SSRS and if so what would the new format/function/etc be? The result should be 0.00 for 0.001.

Comment: Did you try `N2` as the format expression?, it should work as you want

Comment: N2 doesn't work as required, it changes the negative values to positive, and we require negative values to stay negative and display parenthesis around the number rather than -

Comment: I would handle your precision in the dataset that is obtained and then match formatting in SSRS off of that.  EG: SQL: Select Cast(thing as decimal(5,2)), SSRS: Format = "0.00;(0.00)" OR Select Cast(thing as decimal(5,3)), SSRS: Format = "0.000;(0.000)".  That is my suggestion as I know having differences of precision from one system to another sometimes complicates things.

Comment: @dirtyw0lf it changes negative values to positive?, that's wrong, I've never seen that behaviour before.

Comment: @djangojazz the issue is we must display 2 decimal precision in the report but the dataset contains 3 decimals. (i.e. Dataset = 0.001, SSRS interprets as 0.00). Your suggestion would work if the report allows 3 decimals.

Comment: @Lamak negative 0s become positive.

Comment: @dirtyw0lf what does that mean?, what is a negative 0?

Comment: I am suggesting you cast your value in your 'Dataset' in your report to a precision of 2 first before formatting the value in that set.  If it is a select you can do an explicit cast, if it is a procedure you can do an expression for a calculated column '=ROUND(Fields!Field.Value, 2).

Comment: @Lamak, I think the issue is that smaller numbers get rounded to zero before the formatting string is applied, so always have the positive or zero formatting applied, but OP needs this still shown as negative, even when rounded to zero. So they're not being made positive so much as made zero, which means both small negative and positive numbers get the same (zero) formatting applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an interesting one. I replicated your results:

[image]

For the last column I used the following expression in the TextBox:

```
=Switch(Fields!val.Value = 0.0, "---"
    , Fields!val.Value > 0.0, Format(Fields!val.Value, "#,0.00")
    , Fields!val.Value < 0.0, Format(Fields!val.Value, "(#,0.00);(#,0.00)"))
```

This gives the results you require.

Looks good, right? Maybe... For displaying on a web page or exporting to PDF I think this is fine, if annoying, but for exporting to Excel, since you're using `Format`, a string is explicitly returned in the report and hence will be a string in the Excel export, as opposed to be exported as a number as it would be in the first three columns.

Only you can say if this will be a problem in your environment.

I don't think there is a way to get around SSRS treating small numbers as zero, so handling it in the Textbox itself might be your only option.

Comment: @Ian Preston, this is one way to do it correctly. Our reports have hundreds of columns and we decided not to take this route, but instead see if a general solution that is column independant could take care of the issue. Changing every format would take weeks if we had to include the name of the field in every expression. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, @dirtyw0lf, I don't think I have any particular further advice. I'll be the first to admit this isn't a scalable solution, but unfortunately the native formatting behaviour doesn't leave many options. The only thing I could possible consider would be some sort of automated smart find and replace in the RDL files, but I would imagine the chances of your reports/data working with this would be practically nil, and even then difficult to implement. Sorry I can't help further.

Comment: Its ok. Thanks everyone for your assistance on this.